# How to get Default Time format values when changed to unknown format in System C# WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

In my application, i am using wpf toolkit's DateTimeUpDown control to display current time in the format HH:mm:ss. If user change the system time format to custom time format(unknown format), my control should display the default time format values as earlier.. How do i do this?
My application should continue to work regardless of any custom format has been applied...

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YJys.png]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `T` [format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
FormatString="T"
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
<tk:DateTimeUpDown Format="LongTime" />
```

Comment: Its catching exception saying that String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.